# Default value to properties when value is not assigned

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm converting `form value` to `object` which is passed to API after few logic. But when i convert the properties which doesn't show in the UI on a validation sets its default value to `empty` even if the data type is `number` or `boolean` or `date`.

**//Class:**

```
export class Detail{
id: number;
address: string;
active: boolean;
statusId: number;

 public constructor(init?: Partial<Detail>) {
       
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}
```

**//Compoennt:**

```
 let detail = new Detail(this.DetailForm.value);
 console.log(detail)
```

where in a condition, the `active` and `statusId` field is hidden and the user just selects the `id` and type in `address`.

**//on console log this gives**

```
id:5
address: 'abc xyz'
active: ''
statusId: ''
```

**//Expected output:**
I expect when the property is not set, it should have its default.

```
id:5
address: 'abc xyz'
active: false
statusId: 0
```

**//Tried:**

1. Set default value in the property class `active: boolean = false`
2. Set default value in the class in constructor.

   init.active = init.active ?? false;
   init.statusId = init.statusId ?? 0;
   Object.assign(this, init);

After the `Object.assign` it turned back to `empty`

Any ideas to handle such issue for all the data types (like `date` too).

Answer (score 1):

I would use the nullish operator:

```
public constructor(init?: Partial<Detail>) {
    init.active = init.active ?? false;
    init.statusId = init.statusId ?? 0;

       
    Object.assign(this, init);
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but after the object assign it changed to empty

Comment: What if you set the `active` and `statusId` as optional and remove the `Partial` from the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I am missing something here but this worked for me.

```js
export class Detail {
  id: number = 5;
  address: string = "abc xyz";
  active: boolean = false;
  statusId: number = 0;

  public constructor(init?: Partial<Detail>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}


const test1 = new Detail({ id: 3})
const test2 = new Detail();
const test3 = new Detail({id: 3, statusId: 4, address: "my-address"});
console.log(test1);
console.log(test2);
console.log(test3);
```

Expected output:

```
Detail { id: 3, address: 'abc xyz', active: false, statusId: 0 }
Detail { id: 5, address: 'abc xyz', active: false, statusId: 0 }
Detail { id: 3, address: 'my-address', active: false, statusId: 4 }
```

Comment: Is that a possibility that's something is happening in the `form.value`

Comment: This solution works: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiCmAXMBLE0DeAoa0UBMAuaAOwFcBbAI3gCdoBeaAVgG4dox99b4piIiWihIBzRtABEYKsGgAPAJ4AvSe1xhgiFADd4xKgHtDIeGBISAZmBAR466ILCIyEAJJFSlGvSYAGdg4ABzIqEBQ5YEMSQVoyLUNaAAoRFEQAfmIABTBabRsAHgRkNAA+AEpMDlwAeSoAK3gtADpICBRREiTEAAsUCAAaPBI08ocAXyxJrCiYxGhEPkQARgkSeAB3OCRUECSMPE8AZnHymejBBaWAJjXN7ZK9sfO5q8Eju63i3f2CYiOhk4XO5PAAWIZcHh8CDESQURQAWkhvCgklO7FmEBM8GaIEMom6S2Wz0x2Nx+MJgmuJIuZLxBMW7zGQA

Comment: @ACoder yes, it looks like you are not passing, what you think you are.

Comment: This won't work, since the props have values (empty string), and they are not `null` nor `undefined`. Check my answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add default values directly to the class fields. Here is an example of this can be achieved:

//Class

```
export class Detail{
    id: number = 5;
    address: string = 'abc xyz';
    active: boolean = false;
    statusId: number = 0;
    
     public constructor(init?: Partial<Detail>) {
           
            Object.assign(this, init);
        }
    }
```

"Object.assign" will overwrite fields if provided.

Comment: Tried this, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Since the values are `empty` string (not null/undefined), then you can use the OR `||` operator instead of nullish `??`, like the following:

```js
public constructor(init?: Partial<Detail>) {
    init.active = init.active || false;
    init.statusId = init.statusId || 0;
       
    Object.assign(this, init);
}
```